# Issues with R's plot: expr did not evaluate to an object of length n

Tags: r

I want to plot this function in R:

[image]

My code:

```
   lambda <- function (i) {
    m <- 50
    j=max(1,i+m)
    n <- 27090
    ((2*m+1)^(-1))*
    for (i in j:min(n,i+m)) {
    sum (fires_2009_2015$Wi)[j]
    }
    }
    plot(lambda)
```

However when I run the code, I get an error:

> "Error in curve(expr = x, from = from, to = to, xlim = xlim, ylab = ylab,  : 
>     'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n' "

Comment: How this this `fires_2009_2015$Wi` look like?

Comment: you cant write plot(lambda)

Comment: j=max(1,i+m) and i am not sure if this will evaluate either max has to get a vector in order to work j=max(c(1,i+m))

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos:  `max` can handle multiple arguments.  One problem for Paula is that it will give a single answer, and since `i` will be a vector, that's wrong.  `pmax` would fix that problem, but there are other vector problems later in her function.

Comment: @user2554330 you are right

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `plot(lambda)` will call the function `lambda()` with a vector argument for `i`, and your definition of `lambda()` won't handle that properly.  Because of your `for` loop, it looks a little tricky to make it handle vector arguments efficiently, but there's always the brute force method:

```
lambda <- Vectorize(lambda)
```

After this your `plot(lambda)` should do something.  It's probably not what you want, because it will default to a range from 0 to 1, but you can do things like

```
plot(lambda, from = 0, to = 20)
```

to change the default range.